# How do to tighten the bounds of my 'matplotlib' figures to be closer to my axes?

Tags: python, matplotlib, bounds, figure, axes

When `matplotlib` makes figures, I find that it "pads" the space around axes too much for my taste (and in an asymmetrical way). For example with

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

x, y = 12*np.random.rand(2, 1000)
ax.set(xlim=[2,10])
ax.plot(x, y, 'go')
```

I get something that looks like

[image]

(here for example in Adobe Illustrator).

I'd like the bounds of the figure to be closer to the axes on all sides, especially on the left and right.

How can I adjust these bounds programmatically in `matplotlib`, relative to each axis?

Comment: You can use add_axes and specify the bounds manually, [0,0,1,1] would fully span the figure. Adjusting it later can be done with fig.subplot_adjust().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
plt.tight_layout()
```

the default parameter set is:

```
plt.tight_layout(pad=1.08, h_pad=None, w_pad=None, rect=None)
```

Comment: How does this compare to using `savefig('test.png', bbox_inches='tight')`.

Comment: @raxacoricofallapatorius - The effect is similar, but using `bbox_inches='tight'` automatically selects a sub-region of the figure to save, while `tight_layout` alters the layout of the figure.  In other words, if you were to call `plt.show()`, `tight_layout` would change what is displayed interactively, while savefig with `bbox_inches="tight"` wouldn't.